# Why my topN percentile is not updated in careers?

Tags: support, jobs, top-users

Why my topN percentile is not updated in careers? [Here i'm in 4% (10%) for scala](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag), but on careers page - i'm still in 20%.

Comment: Most likely we determine that on the Careers side with a different query than what's on data explorer. I'll see if I can find out.

Comment: maybe it should be http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/256810/333779/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both comments are correct. Let me clarify a little:

- The data explorer [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50844/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag) in your question gives your top placement relative to *all users with a **non-null** total score* in the scala tag: you're top **4%**
- The data explorer [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/256810/333779/what-percentile-am-i-in-for-a-given-tag) in your comment gives your top placement relative to *all users with a total score **greater than 5*** in the scala tag: you're top **11%** (here your are  competing only against users with a higher score)
- The top % shown in your [Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/konddmy) is your placement relative to *all **Careers users** with a linked SO account and a total score greater than 5*:  you're top **11%**. It is the same % as the previous case, but that's just because the Careers users are rather representative of the SO users for this tag.

Careers rounds the top % to the higher multiple of 10: you can be either **top 10%**, **top 20%** or **top 30%** (if higher than that, it is not displayed).

So even though your *real* placement is 11%, it shows as top 20%.

As en encouragement, your total score in scala is **116**, and the *current* threshold to be top 10% is **138**. You're getting there ;)

Comment: yeah :). is it possible to replace original version with my changed script somehow? because i found several questions that use original query.

Comment: It's not possible to replace the original query afaik. The link would have to be updated in these questions